# How does creating reference variable work in C++ internally?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-leaks

I'm trying to grasp how internally reference variable work. Is it a kind of pointer?

I asked to GPT, it said no memory is allocated, it just adds to the symbol table. But doesn't adding a variable to the symbol table allocate in the memory?

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: It depends, it might be implemented as a pointer, it might not be implemented at all, depends on how and where it's used